# Save custom property in Outlook MailItem permanently

Tags: c#, outlook

I’m coding a simple C# program that tries to store some custom properties in a Outlook MailItem as metadata…
I created this simple method in order to write a single property:

```
public static void AddCustomPropertyToEmail(Outlook.MailItem mail, string propKey, object propValue){
  if (propValue is System.Int32) { // INT
    mail.UserProperties.Add(propKey, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olInteger,true, Outlook.OlFormatInteger.olFormatIntegerPlain);
}
  else if (propValue is System.Double){ // DOUBLE
mail.UserProperties.Add(propKey,Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olCurrency,true,Outlook.OlFormatCurrency.olFormatCurrencyDecimal);
}

  mail.UserProperties[propKey].Value = propValue;
  mail.Save();
}
```

and this in order to read a single property:

```
public static string GetCustomPropertyFromEmail(Outlook.MailItem mail, string propKey){
   return (mail.UserProperties[propKey] != null) ? mail.UserProperties[propKey].Value.ToString() : null;
}
```

When I print at Console each property that I’ve added before the print goes fine only if I read the property from the same MailItem type stored in memory…
For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args){

   Outlook.Application outlookObj = new Outlook.Application();
   Outlook.MailItem m1 = GetCurrentEmailItem(outlookObj);

  AddCustomPropertyToEmail(m1, “Int”, 100);
  AddCustomPropertyToEmail(m1, “Double”, 2.0003);

   Console.WriteLine(GetCustomPropertyFromEmail(m2, “Int”));
   Console.WriteLine(GetCustomPropertyFromEmail(m2, “Double”));

    if (m1 != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(m1);
    Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

This program works fine, it prints the values!!!

But the follow code does not, it returns null in each case:

```
 static void Main(string[] args){

   Outlook.Application outlookObj = new Outlook.Application();
   Outlook.MailItem m1 = GetCurrentEmailItem(outlookObj);

   AddCustomPropertyToEmail(m1, “Int”, 100);
   AddCustomPropertyToEmail(m1, “Double”, 2.0003);

   m1.SaveAs(@”C:\PWS\myMail.msg”, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);

  Outlook.MailItem m2 = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookObj.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
  m2 = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookObj.Session.OpenSharedItem(@”C:\PWS\myMail.msg”);

   // HERE THE PROGRAM PRINTS NULL
   Console.WriteLine(GetCustomPropertyFromEmail(m2, “Int”));
   Console.WriteLine(GetCustomPropertyFromEmail(m2, “Double”));

   if (m2 != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(m2);
   Console.ReadKey();
   }
```

My question is: How can I save/store custom property in a MailItem, and possibly save a related msg file in my PWS and read these custom properties in a second time???

Answer (score 1):

You need to call MailItem.Save to persist the changes.

Comment: @Dimitry- At the end of AddCustomPropertyToEmail() function I call mail.Save(). Isn't it enough?

Comment: That should be enough. Check with OutlookSpy (click OpenIMsgOnIStg) that the MSG file really has your custom properties. Also, UserProperties.Add returns the UserProperty object. There is no reason to add it first (ignoring the result), then access it again using mail.UserProperties[].

Comment: @Dimitry- When I look to the custom properties by the Windows Explorer there are not items! It seems that the 'UserProperties.Add()' method saves custom properties only inside MailItem that are in the Inbox folder. By saving a MailItem to .msg format does not allow to store these information inside the file.

Comment: How can you look at the properties in Windows Explorer? What does OpenIMsgOnIStg in OutlookSpy show?